# AngularJS Jasmine Unit Testing : Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: pServiceProvider <- pService

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-ngmock

I am doing testing on a simple angular code but I am getting the following error.

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: pServiceProvider <- pService

Here are the details:

ProdModule.JS

```
var sapp = angular.module('productsApp', []);
```

ProdController.js

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />
/// <reference path="ProdModule.js" />


sapp.controller('ProductsController', function productsController($scope,      
pService) {
$scope.products = pService();
});
```

ProdService.js

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />
/// <reference path="ProdModule.js" />
// register the service

sapp.service('pService', function pService() {
return function getProducts() {
    return [{ name: 'Chai' }, { name: 'Syrup' }];
}
});
```

Test.JS

```
 /// <reference path="../jasmine/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="../dependencies/ProdModule.js" />
/// <reference path="../dependencies/ProdService.js" />
/// <reference path="../dependencies/ProdController.js" />

describe('Prod', function () {
beforeEach(module('productsApp'));
var $controller;
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    console.log($controller)
}));
it('should return products list on load', function () {
    var $scope = {};
    var productsController = $controller(function inlineController($scope,   
 pService) {
        $scope.products = pService();
    }, { $scope: $scope });

    expect($scope.products).toEqual([{ name: 'Chai' }, { name: 'Syrup' }]);
});
})
```

When I put Service code in ProdController.js then it works pefectly but when I seperate the code into each js file then the testing breaks. May I know what am I missing?

Comment: Shoudn't you send pService along with $scope when calling var productsController = $controller ?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you. can you type the code?

Comment: Actually, forget that. You said it works if ProdService.js and ProdController.js are together in one file, right? So it must be a bundling issue... I assume you are using Typescript. Are you sure the files are getting bundled?

Comment: nope. it is not getting bundled and i am not even using typescript